# How to differenciate between NULL data and 0 in sqlite-net?

Tags: c#, ios, sqlite, xamarin, sqlite-net

I am working on an iOS app with `Xamarin`. I am using the sqlite-net ORM to interact with my database.

With an Integer column, the ORM returns a `Int32` value. However, the value in this column can be `NULL`. And I noticed that if this is the case, it will return 0 instead of `NULL` since it is impossible to set an int to `NULL`.

For instance, with the following code :

```
public class Client
{
    public Client ()
    {
    }

    [PrimaryKey, Column("ID")]
    public string ID{ get; set;}

    public string FirstName{ get; set;}
    public string LastName{ get; set;}
    public int    Age{ get; set;}
}
```

If the ID is correct but the FirstName, LastName and Age are set to `NULL`, the returned object will have null in the FirstName and LastName fields, which is logical. But the Age will be set to zero.
So I cannot know if the value is `NULL` or really 0. Is there a way to differentiate those cases ?

Comment: Any chance to declare Age as `int?` ?

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you mean, Age is already declared as int

Comment: Nullable<int> or int? was introduced in C# 2.0

Comment: sqlite-net does not return a Nullable<int>. It returns an Int32. The problem is that the ORM returns 0 when the value is set to NULL in the database

Comment: I realized my mistake with James Russo's answer. Sqlite return types depend on the type of your variable. If it is an int, it will return an Int32. If it is a Nullable<int>, it will return the same type. And it will be able to return NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally your Client class is telling us that "Age" is a non-nullable property.  But what is important to realize here is that "Age", being an integer, is actually a Value Type.

Value Types can not contain a null value.  Unless combined with "?" or "Nullable<>" as pointed out already.

In .NET string is actually not a Value Type but a Reference Type.

Thu-sly, this is why you get a null value on your string properties but not on your integer property.

One other thing to note, is SQLite.NET by default creates nullable columns, in order to force a non-nullable column is to add the attribute: [NotNullAttribute] above your property.

The only why to allow "Age" to be returned from the database as a null is to write the following properties:

```
public class Client
{
public Client ()
{
}

public Nullable<int> Age{ get; set;}
//public int? Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked ! My mistake came from the fact that in my code (not the sample I have put in the question) I had Nullable<MyEnum>. And I had an error since it was not able to cast the return type to Nullable<MyEnum>. So I thought that it returned an Int32, and therefore that it was not able to return NULL.